# Program to convert binary to hex

Tags: c, number-systems

I wrote this program to convert binary to hex, it ignores other characters between the binary digits. I would like to receive any recommendations on how to improve it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const char table[] = "0123456789abcdef";

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int flip = argc - 2;
  unsigned char* ubin = argv[1];
  unsigned int nibble = 0;
  int i = 0;
  int nothing = 1;

  if((argc != 2) && (argc != 3 || strcmp(argv[2], "-f") != 0)){
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s 00001111 [-f]\n", argv[0]);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  printf("%s", "0x");

  while(*ubin){
    if((*ubin != '0') && (*ubin != '1')){
      ++ubin;
      continue;
    }

    nibble <<= 1;
    nibble |= *ubin - '0';

    if(++i == 4){
      i = 0;
      if(flip)
        nibble = ~nibble & 0xf;
      putchar(table[nibble]);
      nibble = 0;
      nothing = 0;
    }

    ++ubin;    
  }

  if(nothing)
    putchar('0');

  putchar('\n');

  if(i)
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %d bits were discarded, min unit is a nibble\n", i);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const char table[] = "0123456789abcdef";
```

This constant should be `static const char table[]`. Just as a general rule, so that it doesn’t conflict with other variables in other files that are also called `table`.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int flip = argc - 2;
  unsigned char* ubin = argv[1];
```

Using `argc` and `argv` before range checking them is dangerous in general. In this case it works, but it means that `ubin` could be `NULL` here. This code looks suspicious.

```
  unsigned int nibble = 0;
  int i = 0;
```

Bad variable name `i`. It should rather be `nbits`, since it contains the number of bits in the current nibble.

```
  int nothing = 1;

  if((argc != 2) && (argc != 3 || strcmp(argv[2], "-f") != 0)){
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s 00001111 [-f]\n", argv[0]);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  printf("%s", "0x");
```

A simple `printf("0x")` would be clearer.

```
  while(*ubin){
```

Instead of this `while` loop, write a `for` loop: `for (ubin = argv[1]; *ubin != '\0'; ubin++) {`. Then you don’t need to write the `ubin++` multiple times.

```
    if((*ubin != '0') && (*ubin != '1')){
      ++ubin;
      continue;
    }

    nibble <<= 1;
    nibble |= *ubin - '0';

    if(++i == 4){
      i = 0;
      if(flip)
        nibble = ~nibble & 0xf;
```

An alternative would be `nibble ^= 0xf;`.

```
      putchar(table[nibble]);
      nibble = 0;
      nothing = 0;
    }

    ++ubin;    
  }

  if(nothing)
    putchar('0');

  putchar('\n');

  if(i)
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %d bits were discarded, min unit is a nibble\n", i);
```

In case of an error, the return value should be `EXIT_FAILURE`, not 0.

```
  return 0;
}
```

But apart from all these comments, the program looks fine. You did the argument checking correctly and strictly. When your program gets more options, you should consider using the `getopt` library for parsing the command line. But for now, it is fine.

It is unusual to have the options after the remaining arguments; `-f 00001111` is more common than `00001111 -f`.

The main algorithm is clean and simple. I especially like the error handling at the end. There are too many other programs that just don’t do this.

Comment: Concerning "A simple `printf("0x")`"   `fputs("0x", stdout)` is a nice alternative.  The trouble with `printf("0x")`" is that _in general_, `printf()` expects a _format_ string and obliges care when a `%` is might in the future be part of the general purpose string, as you suggest.  With this simple code - really makes no difference, yet I would not label `printf("0x");` a strongly preferred practice over `printf("%s", "0x");`.